# incompatible types: com.google.common.collect.ForwardingImmutableMap cannot be converted to com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap generated-sources

Tags: java, gwt, generated-code

When I start my wildfly in debug modue I get the following error in
project-parent\project-frontend\target\generated-sources\gwt\com\google\common\collect\ForwardingImmutableMap_FieldSerializer.java:17:84

```
java: incompatible types: com.google.common.collect.ForwardingImmutableMap cannot be converted to com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap
```

My problem: I have fixed this file but when I rerun the debugger the file gets generated automatically.
How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

try adding

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>31.0.1-jre</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
        <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Here's a link for update: https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#removed